# zoom slider of the map is very small

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, openlayers

i am studying this example in the link below:

i would like to add zoom slider as at the left side below th plus and the minus signs.
when i use the code posted in the above posted link, i get the zoom slider very small and tiny as shown in the image below.

please let me know how to add width and height to the zoom slider to appear

**app.component.html**:

```
<div class="MousePosition">
  <div id="mouse-position"></div>
</div>
<form>
  <label for="projection">Projection </label>
  <select id="projection">
    <option value="EPSG:4326">EPSG:4326</option>
    <option value="EPSG:3857">EPSG:3857</option>
  </select>
  <label for="precision">Precision</label>
  <input id="precision" type="number" min="0" max="12" value="4"/>
</form>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
<style>
  .map {
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
  }
  /**
   * The zoomslider in the second map shall be placed between the zoom-in and
   * zoom-out buttons.
   */
  #map2 .ol-zoom .ol-zoom-out {
    margin-top: 204px;
  }
  #map2 .ol-zoomslider {
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 2.3em;
  }

  #map2 .ol-touch .ol-zoom .ol-zoom-out {
    margin-top: 212px;
  }
  #map2 .ol-touch .ol-zoomslider {
    top: 2.75em;
  }

  #map2 .ol-zoom-in.ol-has-tooltip:hover [role=tooltip],
  #map2 .ol-zoom-in.ol-has-tooltip:focus [role=tooltip] {
    top: 3px;
  }

  #map2 .ol-zoom-out.ol-has-tooltip:hover [role=tooltip],
  #map2 .ol-zoom-out.ol-has-tooltip:focus [role=tooltip] {
    top: 232px;
  }

  /**
   * The zoomslider in the third map shall be horizontal, placed in the top-right
   * corner, smaller and orange.
   */
  #map3 .ol-zoomslider {
    top: 8px;
    left: auto;
    right: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(255,69,0,0.2);
    width: 200px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(255,69,0);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  #map3 .ol-zoomslider:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,69,0,0.3);
  }

  #map3 .ol-zoomslider-thumb {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    filter: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,69,0,0.6);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  #map3 a.ol-zoomslider-handle:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,69,0,0.7);
  }
</style>
<style>
#map {
width: 1000px;
height: 550px;
}
  /**
   * The zoomslider in the third map shall be horizontal, placed in the top-right
   * corner, smaller and orange.
   */
  #map .ol-zoomslider {
    top: 8px;
    left: auto;
    right: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(255,69,0,0.2);
    width: 200px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(255,69,0);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  #map .ol-zoomslider:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,69,0,0.3);
  }

  #map .ol-zoomslider-thumb {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    filter: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,69,0,0.6);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  #map a.ol-zoomslider-handle:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,69,0,0.7);
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit() {
this. map = new Map({
controls: defaultControls().extend([mousePositionControl]),
target: 'map',//<---i want to change this
layers: [
  new TileLayer({
    source: new XYZSource({
      url: 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
    })
  })
],
view: new View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 0
})
});
 }

var zoomslider = new ZoomSlider();
this.map.addControl(zoomslider);
```

**image**:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are not including the ol.css file

Comment: @MoonE would you please tell me how to included it..I am new to angular with open layer programming please